# mysql how to update a column of every row with a given set of values

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, sql-update

I want to update a column for every row of a table with a value from a given set of values.  So for example:

```
id     name     code
---------------------
1      n1       
2      n2     
3      n3
```

And i have this array of values ['code-1','code-2','code3'] that I want to set to every row, so for row one the value for code column will be 'code-1' from array, and row two the value for code column will be 'code-2' and for row three value for code column will be 'code-3' from array.  So the final table will look like this:

```
id     name     code
---------------------
1      n1       code-1
2      n2       code-2
3      n3       code-3
```

How can i do this in one sql query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
update table t
    set code = concat('code-', id)
    where id in (1, 2, 3);
```

If the codes aren't really tied to the ids, you can use a `case`:

```
update table t
    set code = (case when id = 1 then 'code-1'
                     when id = 2 then 'code-2'
                     when id = 3 then 'code-3'
                end)
    where id in (1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: this is great, but how would you go about it if you have over 100 records?

Comment: This would work fine for 100 values, but I would probably be storing the id/value pairs in a table and use a `join` for the update.

Answer (score 2):

create a new table (temp) to hold the array with a schema like this

```
id       code
-------------
1       code-1
2       code-2
3       code-3
```

and update your original table with this update statement

```
UPDATE original
SET code = temp.code
FROM original INNER JOIN temp
ON original.id = temp.id
```

Comment: i c so theres no sql statement specifically for this situation?  i have to do so with more than one sql statement right?

Comment: If you count the statements needed to create the temp table and inserting into it, then yes you can't do it with one statement, but the actual update is done in a single shot.

Answer (score 0):

How do you identify "row one" in the table? How about "row two"?

To get to an UPDATE statement, I'd start first with a SELECT statement that returns the rows along with the new values to be assigned.

The "array" you currently have, it would be easiest if that were converted to a table. If you don't want to define a table and load it, we can use an inline view, but the size of the statement may be a limitation.

If we run this query, for example:

```
  SELECT 1 AS rownum, 'code-1' AS code
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'code-2'
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'code-3'
```

We get back three rows in a resultset, that we can reference like a table. Extend that with additional `UNION ALL SELECT` to add additional rows.

For getting corresponding `rownum` values from the table we want to update, we return the primary key (or unique non null key), and return those in the order we want, so the first row gets a rownum of 1, the second row gets a rownum of 2, etc. As an example:

```
  SELECT r.id
       , @rn := @rn + 1 AS rowumn
    FROM mytable r
   CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @rn := 0 ) i
   ORDER BY r.name, r.id
```

With those two results, we can join back to the table we want to update, returning the new code value we want to assign to the row, for example:

```
  SELECT t.id
       , t.name
       , t.code AS old_code
       , c.code AS new_code
       , o.rownum
    FROM ( SELECT 1 AS rownum, 'code-1' AS code
           UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'code-2'
           UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'code-3'
         ) c
    JOIN ( SELECT r.id
                , @rn := @rn + 1 AS rowumn
            FROM mytable r
            CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @rn := 0 ) i
            ORDER BY r.name, r.id
         ) o
      ON o.rownum = c.rownum
    JOIN mytable t
      ON t.id = o.id
```

Once we're satisfied that's returning the rows we want to update, and the new values we want to assign to each row, we can convert that into an `UPDATE` statement by replacing `SELECT ... FROM` with `UPDATE`, and adding a `SET` clause at the end of the statement. (Before the `WHERE` clause if we have a `WHERE` clause.)

```
  UPDATE ( SELECT 1 AS rownum, 'code-1' AS code
           UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'code-2'
           UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'code-3'
         ) c
    JOIN ( SELECT r.id
                , @rn := @rn + 1 AS rowumn
            FROM mytable r
            CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @rn := 0 ) i
            ORDER BY r.name, r.id
         ) o
      ON o.rownum = c.rownum
    JOIN mytable t
      ON t.id = o.id 
     SET t.code = c.code
```

That's how I'd do it.

If the number of rows in the "new code" array is large, I'd create a table, and load the array values into the table. Then replace the inline view query `c` with a reference to the table.

```
    FROM my_new_code_table c
```

Or, I could break the statement up into manageable chunks. Do 20 codes, and then for the next set of 20 rows:

```
       ( SELECT 21 AS rownum, 'code-21' AS code 
         UNION ALL SELECT 22, 'code-22'
         ... 
         UNION ALL SELECT 40, 'code-40'
       ) c
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a different solution to my problem, because i had thousands of entrys to correct using joins:

```
UPDATE `entry`
JOIN 
( *DEFINE QUERY FOR LOOKUPTABLE HERE* ) as alias
on alias.id=entry.valuetoreplace
SET `valuetoreplace` = alias.newvalue;
```