# in mysql how to set a column for every row in a table from a give set of values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, rows

I have this table:

```
id      name     code
---------------------------
1        n1  
2        n2
3        n3
```

and I have these values that need to be written to the code column of every row:

```
('8n8kKaVu','SRE2vbpQ','Vdfb7V7s')
```

Also, it does not matter which row a value from the above table gets set to.  So lets say i want the final table to look like this:

```
id     name     code
-----------------------
1      n1       8n8kKaVu
2      n2       SRE2vbpQ
3      n3       Vdfb7V7s
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql how to update a column of every row with a given set of values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237117/mysql-how-to-update-a-column-of-every-row-with-a-given-set-of-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load all the codes into a table, you could create an auto-incrementing key:

```
alter table codes add id integer auto_increment key;
```

Then update the code column in the original table with the values in the codes table:

```
UPDATE original_table
SET code = (SELECT
                codes.code
            FROM codes
            WHERE original_table.id = codes.id);
```